# How to load document with a custom _id by Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my schema definition:

```
var DocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    name: String,
    path: String
  },
  label: String,
  ...
});
mongoose.model('Doc', DocSchema, 'doc_parse_utf8');
var Doc = mongoose.model('Doc');
```

And the documents have been inserted to mongodb by other program. Then I tried to query the document:

```
Doc.findOne({_id:{name:name,path:path}}, function(err, doc){
  if (err && err_handler) {
    err_handler(err);
  } else if(callback) {
    callback(doc);
  }
});
```

But, a cast error will be reported:

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: { name: 'mobile', path: 'etc/' },
  path: '_id' }
```

I have searched this problem on mongoose's document, google and statckoverflow.com, however, there's no any solution for me. Please help, thanks.

Comment: According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoose-orm/yp_hHanUruo/ffM3WQPD-i8J) from the Mongoose author, it's (surprisingly) not supported.

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is override the `_id` type by setting it to `Mixed`.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    name: String
});
```

This causes Mongoose to essentially ignore the details of the object.

Now, when you use `find`, it will work (nearly as expected).

I'd warn you that you'll need to be certain that the order of properties on the `_id` object you're using must be provided in the exact same order or the `_id`s will not be considered to be identical.

When I tried this for example:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var testId = { name: 'wiredprairie', group: 'abc'};
var u = new User({_id: testId , name: 'aaron'});

u.save(function(err, results) {
    User.find().where("_id", testId)
        .exec(function(err, users) {
            console.log(users.length); 
    });
});
```

The console output was `0`.

I noticed that the actual data in MongoDB was stored differently than I thought it had been saved:

```
{ 
  "_id" : { 
       "group" : "abc", 
       "name" : "wiredprairie" 
  }, 
  "name" : "aaron",
  "__v" : 0 
}
```

As you can see, it's not `name` then `group` as I'd coded. (It was alphabetical, which made sense in retrospect).

So, instead, I did this:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var testId = { name: 'wiredprairie', group: 'abc'};
var u = new User({_id: testId , name: 'aaron'});

u.save(function(err, results) {
    User.find().where("_id", { group: 'abc', name: 'wiredprairie'})
        .exec(function(err, users) {
            console.log(users.length);
    });
});
```

Then, the console output was `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re-design your schema. If the database is already on service, and can not change it now, you can temporary use this to solve the problem:

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
  mongoose.connection.db.collection('doc_parse_utf8').find({
      _id: {
        name: 'mobile',
        path: 'etc/'
      }
  }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      console.log(err || docs)
  })  
})
```

As I know if you choose different order of fields in object `find` method will not work because

```
  _id: {
    name: 'mobile',
    path: 'etc/'
  }
```

and

```
  _id: {
    path: 'etc/',
    name: 'mobile'
  }
```

are different keys.